# Java reading in character streams with supplementary unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, astral-plane, supplementary

I'm having trouble reading in supplementary unicode characters using Java.  I have a file that potentially contains characters in the supplementary set (anything greater than \uFFFF).  When I setup my InputStreamReader to read the file using UTF-8 I would expect the read() method to return a single character for each supplementary character, instead it seems to split on the 16 bit threshold.

I saw some other questions about basic unicode character streams, but nothing seems to deal with the greater than 16 bit case.

Here's some simplified sample code:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(file, "UTF8");
int nextChar = input.read();
while(nextChar != -1) {
    ...
    nextChar = input.read();
}
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to correctly read in a UTF-8 encoded file that contains supplementary characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java works with [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). So, if your input stream has astral characters, they will appear as a surrogate pair, i.e., as two `char`s. The first character is the high surrogate, and the second character is the low surrogate.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there an easy way to tell if a character is the first of a  surrogate pair?

Comment: Sure, use `Character.isHighSurrogate()`. (There's also `Character.isLowSurrogate()` for the second half of the surrogate pair.)

Comment: Or, use String.codePointAt() / Character.codePointAt() methods, if you know index of the first character that forms surrogate pair.

Comment: Awesome that seems to work. One last question... I have a regular expression that uses unicode character classes (such as "\p{Nd}"), these classes seem to not work on these surrogate pairs.  Is there an easy solution to that?

Comment: Here's a link with a detailed discussion of coding for supplementary characters and surrogate code points in Java:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-unicode/

Answer (score 1):

Though `read()` is defined to return `int`, and could theoretically return a supplementary character's code point "all at once", I believe the return type is only `int` to allow a value of -1 to be returned.

The value you're getting from `read()` is basically a `char` by another name, and Java a `char` is limited to 16 bits.

Java can only represent supplementary characters as a UTF-16 surrogate pair, there is no such thing as a "single character" (at least in the `char` sense) once you get above 0xFFFF as far as Java is concerned.

Comment: Mostly true, although JDK does expose concept of "code point", which is the 32-bit full unicode value decoded out of UCS-2 (~= UTF-16) characters. So while char is limited to 16 bits, Java is not oblivious to the fact that Unicode code points extend beyond 16 bits.