# How to read non-BMP (astral) Unicode supplementary characters (code points)

Tags: java, unicode, codepoint, surrogate-pairs, supplementary

The G-Clef (U+1D11E) is not part of the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (BMP), which means that it requires more than 16 bit. Almost all of Java's read functions return only a `char` or a `int` containing also [only 16 bit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29). Which function reads complete Unicode symbols including SMP, SIP, TIP, SSP and PUA?

**Update**

I have asked how to read a single Unicode symbol (or code point) from a input stream. I neither have any integer array nor do I want to read a line.

It is possible to build a code point with `Character.toCodePoint()` but this function requires a `char`. On the other side reading a `char` is not possible because `read()` returns an `int`.  My best work around so far is this but it still contains unsafe casts:

```
public int read_code_point (Reader input) throws java.io.IOException
{
  int ch16 = input.read();
  if (Character.isHighSurrogate((char)ch16))
    return Character.toCodePoint((char)ch16, (char)input.read());
  else 
    return (int)ch16;
}
```

How to do it better?

**Update 2**

Another version returning a String but still using casts:

```
public String readchar (Reader input) throws java.io.IOException
{
  int i16 = input.read(); // UTF-16 as int
  if (i16 == -1) return null;
  char c16 = (char)i16; // UTF-16
  if (Character.isHighSurrogate(c16)) {
    int low_i16 = input.read(); // low surrogate UTF-16 as int
    if (low_i16 == -1)
      throw new java.io.IOException ("Can not read low surrogate");
    char low_c16 = (char)low_i16;
    int codepoint = Character.toCodePoint(c16, low_c16);
    return new String (Character.toChars(codepoint));
  }
  else 
    return Character.toString(c16);
}
```

The remaining question: are the casts safe or how to avoid them?

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java reading in character streams with supplementary unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721293/java-reading-in-character-streams-with-supplementary-unicode-characters)

Comment: The possible duplicate does not contain an answer.

Comment: both of your answers are "correct" (although the first doesn't handle end of stream).  nothing about your casts is unsafe.

Comment: Read [*The WTF-8 encoding*](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) decode from potentially ill-formed `UTF-16` to code points and vice versa…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My best work around so far is this but it still contains unsafe casts

The only unsafe thing about the code you've presented is that `ch16` might be -1 if `input` has reached EOF.  If you check for this condition first then you can guarantee that the other `(char)` casts are safe as `Reader.read()` [is specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29) to return either -1 or a value that is within the range of `char` (0 - 0xFFFF).

```
public int read_code_point (Reader input) throws java.io.IOException
{
  int ch16 = input.read();
  if (ch16 < 0 || !Character.isHighSurrogate((char)ch16))
    return ch16;
  else {
    int loSurr = input.read();
    if(loSurr < 0 || !Character.isLowSurrogate((char)loSurr)) 
      return ch16; // or possibly throw an exception
    else 
      return Character.toCodePoint((char)ch16, (char)loSurr);
  }
}
```

This still isn't ideal, really you need to handle the edge case where the first `char` read is a high surrogate but the second one isn't a matching low surrogate, in which case you probably want to return the first `char` as-is *and backup the reader* so that the next read gives you the next character.  But that only works if `input.markSupported() == true`.  If you *can* guarantee that then how about

```
public int read_code_point (Reader input) throws java.io.IOException
{
  int firstChar = input.read();
  if (firstChar < 0 || !Character.isHighSurrogate((char)firstChar)) {
    return firstChar;
  } else {
    input.mark(1);
    int secondChar = input.read();
    if(secondChar < 0) {
      // reached EOF
      return firstChar;
    } else if(!Character.isLowSurrogate((char)secondChar)) {
      // unpaired surrogates, un-read the second char
      input.reset();
      return firstChar;
    }
    else {
      return Character.toCodePoint((char)firstChar, (char)secondChar);
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could wrap the original reader in a `PushbackReader` and use `unread(secondChar)`

Comment: what does converting this to a codepoint gain?  if you want to do anything useful, you most likely want the data in a String.

Comment: @jtahlborn Every parser needs the next character and not the next string. Would you say parsers are not useful?

Answer (score -1):

Full Unicode can be represented in both UTF-8 and UTF-16, by sequences of bytes resp. byte pairs ("java chars"). From String a full Unicode *code point* can be extracted with:

```
int[] codePoints = { 0x1d11e };
String s = new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
    int cp = s.codePointAt(i);
    i += Character.charCount(cp);
}
```

For a file with basically latin characters, UTF-8 would seem fine.

Tho following reads a full standard Unicode file (in UTF-8):

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"))) {
    for (;;) {
        String line = in.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        ... do some thing with a Unicode line ...
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("No file: " + file.getPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

---

A function that delivers a Java String of one (or more Unicode codes):

```
String s = unicodeToString(0x1d11e);
String s = unicodeToString(0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x1d11e);

public static String unicodeToString(int... codepoints) {
    return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
}
```

Comment: Detailed it more; here I read from a file, a FileInputStream. Maybe the confusion is that Unicode in itself is not a format, but standard numbering of symbols. UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-16 are the actual binary formats. In effect Java uses Unicode in 2 formats: though `char` is UTF-16, in .class String constants are stored as UTF-8. **UTF-8 covers full Unicode.** In the code above the array `codePoints` uses the Unicode numbers.

Comment: It question asked for a single symbol not a full line. Using `readline` makes it necessary to unread the rest of the line.

Comment: Ahah, will add it to the answer.